# Is it possible to express an argument and ask for feedback on that argument or would that be "primarily opinion-based"?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

Is it possible to express an argument and ask for feedback on that argument or would that be "primarily opinion-based"? If such questions are not allowed, can someone recommend another venue for getting such feedback on philosophical arguments and ideas?

Comment: Seems okay to me. I don't see why opinions should come into it.

Comment: Most requests for feedback on arguments get closed as "Questions that push a personal philosophy with no question beyond "am I right" or "what do you think" are off-topic here as this is not a blog. It's ok to express unique opinions, but you must have an actual, answerable question to go with them." Which does suggest that a blog is a good way to get feedback...